# Container is not the same height on IOS and Android

Tags: ios, android-studio, dart, flutter, iphone-x

**My container is set to height (110) but in iOS (onlIphoneX) it gets the height with size similar to 90. How to fix it?**

On Android and previous versions of Iphone, it's perfect.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:pequeno_form_flutter/ui/app/login/login_block.dart';

class NavigationDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    // TODO: implement build
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 90,
            child: DrawerHeader(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: color,
              ),
              child: LoginView(),
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Container with wrong height on IphoneX**

[image: Container with wrong height]

**Container with correct height on Iphone 8 plus and earlier.**
[image: Container with correct height on Iphone 8 plus and earlier.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `ListView` in `SafeArea` and you will see the container coming back to original height.

```
SafeArea(child: ListView(...))
```